# apk drag and drop in Genymotion not being able in windows 7

Tags: android, genymotion, virtual-device-manager

I sucessfully installed `GenyMotion` and `synchronized Android Studio` with `Genymotion` by providing the path of installed `Genymotion` folder in my `OS(windows 7)`.

Now I want to run ready application file residing in **hard drive** in `genymotion`. For that I tried to **drag and drop** the `apk` but it is not working.

What i am doing worng?

Comment: Please gives more precision about the problem. Does an error appear? Do the corners are becoming pink when you drag your APK on the devices?

Comment: I have sucessfully installed Genymotion for Android and run test application from Android Studio but when I wish to drag apk files residing in my external drive of Comnputer Genymotion doesnot permit me to drag ....unlike Mac

Comment: What is your current Genymotion version? It should not happens.